# Allow a range of IP's with IPTABLES from a file

Tags: iptables

I would like to allow only certain ip ranges (CIDR) and block everything else, however, I have those IPs that I want to allow on a text file. How could I load them up from the `allow.file` to IPTABLES interface `eth0`?

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head:

```
while read range; do
    iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s $range -j ACCEPT
done < allow.file
```

Addendum: A comment in chat asked whether using `-I INPUT` might be better than `-A INPUT` -- that is, inserting the rule at the beginning of the chain rather than at the end of the chain.  This is, really, a local issue -- I've seen firewall rulesets where inserting would break things, and rulesets where appending would break things.  You've got to make that choice for yourself and your situation.  If you don't know which, then you shouldn't be writing iptables rules by hand, and should be using a management program like shorewall or ufw.

Comment: Sorry, was thinking "IP blacklist".  It should be `ACCEPT`, and I've modified my answer to suit.

Comment: Actually, there's a UUOC in here.. You don't need to cat into while, just do:
... `done < allow.file `
.. instead

Comment: @Tom Well caught.